# Using Json and forms on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, json, forms, clr, casablanca

When I create a form on Visual Studio, the common language RunTime Support changes to /clr, but when I add the libraries of json, I get the following error:

> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

And if I change from /clr for *no common languages*, then I get a lot a errors from the namespaces that I am using.

Any ideia of how I can mix this two things?

I’m using the C++ Rest SDK (Codename “Casablanca”) to parse the json.

Comment: When you add a form, your project changes from C++ (native) to C++CLI (.Net runtime). Those languages are similar, but not the same. C++CLI isn't a good language to develop applications in - it's usually only used to write bridges between native code and .Net code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/561136:

You won't be able to use the C=+ Rest SDK in managed C++/CLI. What you are seeing here is an error in one of our dependencies, atomics, that isn't supported. You will have to keep to using the C++ Rest SDK in the native C++ portions of your application.